# How can i change values that are bound to first parameter (lambda expression) in the html helper function ListBoxFor() method?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, viewmodel

Below is my code of
view:

```
@model MvcDemo.Models.viewmodelCities
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}
<h2>Index</h2>
<div>
    @using (@Html.BeginForm())
    {
        @Html.ListBoxFor(x => x.SelectedCities, Model.Cities, new { 
        size=@Model.Cities.Count()})
        <br/>
        <input type="submit" value="submit" />
    }
</div>
```

model:

```
public class viewmodelCities
    {
        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Cities { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<String> SelectedCities { get; set; }
    }
```

controller action method for Get:

```
[HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            EmployeeDbContext db = new EmployeeDbContext();
            List<SelectListItem> listSelecteditem = new List<SelectListItem>();
            foreach (tblCity city in db.tblCities)
            {
                SelectListItem selectListItem = new SelectListItem()
                {
                    Text = city.Name,
                    Value = city.ID.ToString(),
                    Selected = city.IsSelected
                };
                listSelecteditem.Add(selectListItem);
            }
            viewmodelCities vmc = new viewmodelCities();
            vmc.Cities = listSelecteditem;
            return View(vmc);
        }
```

& controller action method for post:

```
[HttpPost]
        public string Index(IEnumerable<string> SelectedCities)
        {
            if(SelectedCities==null)
            {
                return "You did not select any city";
            }
            else
            {
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                sb.Append("You selected - "+string.Join(",",SelectedCities));
                return sb.ToString();
            }
        }
```

In the output when i select any cities, In the post method their ID's are automatically bound to the IEnumerable.So when i select cities with Id's:3 & 4 i get the below output.

```
You selected - 3,4
```

As you can see in the whole code i'm nowhere inserting values into selectCities. Since i'm newbie into mvc and don't completely understand it's conventions can someone explain how values are getting bound to the IEnumerable during postback? How can i tweak here to post the names of the cities instead of Id's?Is there a way to get around this?
*PS:I got this code from an online tutorial*

Comment: If these items exist in the database, you would use the ID to look up the properties for these rows to obtain your city names. If you don't need to go back to the database you set the value to the city name instead of the ID `Value = city.Name` when you first populate the list.

Comment: As a side note, you can delete the `Selected = city.IsSelected` - its pointless and does nothing when you bind to a model property - its the value of `SelectedCities` that determines want options are selected when the view is generated.

Answer (score 0):

You actually are setting the values for selectCities.

In your view, you have the following form:

```
@using (@Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.ListBoxFor(x => x.SelectedCities, Model.Cities, new { 
    size=@Model.Cities.Count()})
    <br/>
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
}
```

Here, you're using the following line to generate the listbox:

```
    @Html.ListBoxFor(x => x.SelectedCities, Model.Cities, new { size=@Model.Cities.Count()})
```

[Take a look at the documentation for this function.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee830419(v=vs.118).aspx) This is how you're "inserting" the selected cities when you click the button.

Essentially, you are supplying the following to the function:

- `x => x.SelectedCities` --> The cities that are selected in the listbox by default from your viewModel AND the Selectedcities that will be posted to the POST Index method of your controller when you submit the form.
- `Model.Cities` --> All of the available options in the listbox from your viewModel.
- `new { size=@Model.Cities.Count()}` --> Setting the HTML Attribute size.

Because you're using a form, whenever you click the "submit" button, the client sends `IEnumerable<string> SelectedCities` to your POST method, Index. This is how your controller is receiving the selected values and then outputting that text.

Hopefully that helps. I can try to clarify further if needed. I suggest reading the documentation for that function, and the `BeginForm()` function to get some more insight.

EDIT: I realized you were also asking how to set the selectedCities list. You would set this list the same way as you set your Cities member of your ViewModel in your GET Index method on your controller:

```
vmc.Cities = listSelecteditem;
```

You would just need to generate another list of models that represents the cities you want selected. How you implement that function is, of course, up to you.

For example:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    EmployeeDbContext db = new EmployeeDbContext();
    List<SelectListItem> listSelecteditem = new List<SelectListItem>();
    foreach (tblCity city in db.tblCities)
    {
        SelectListItem selectListItem = new SelectListItem()
        {
            Text = city.Name,
            // Tweaked to use Name instead of ID in post.
            Value = city.Name,
            Selected = city.IsSelected
        };
        listSelecteditem.Add(selectListItem);
    }
    viewmodelCities vmc = new viewmodelCities();

    // Simply set your SelectedCities here, and it will be reflected on your page.
    vmc.SelectedCities = SomeService.GetSomeCities(someFilter);

    vmc.Cities = listSelecteditem;
    return View(vmc);
    }
```

where SomeService.GetSomeCities is a function I made up that would return `IEnumerable<String>` of City IDs. I also changed the initialization of the select list to use name as it's value instead of ID.

Answer (score 0):

For a listbox control, the selected values are going to be posted. If you would like the city names instead of the IDs, you can set `Value = city.Name` when you are populating the `SelectList`.

```
foreach (tblCity city in db.tblCities)
{
    SelectListItem selectListItem = new SelectListItem()
    {
        Text = city.Name,
        Value = city.Name, // <-- change to this
        Selected = city.IsSelected
    };
    listSelecteditem.Add(selectListItem);
}
```

Also, if you're interested in code golf, you can use LINQ's `Select()` extension to project your `dbtblCities` into a `List<SelectListItem>` without using a loop explicitly:

```
var listSelecteditem = db.tblCities.Select(x => new SelectListItem {
    Text = city.Name,
    Value = city.Name,
    Selected = city.IsSelected }).ToList();
```